# VIVADO test bench is outputting an error saying that top is a black box

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am trying to learn how to use an FPGA by coding a very simple SOP. The TOP file works well, and when I generate bitstream and put the code on the dev board everything works properly. But then I wanted to test the simulation(I know I should have done it before, but I am just testing the features to learn) and when the test bench is ran I only see the signals that I have declared in the test bench. I found on some forums that you need to link the test bench and the top file, and I done that, but it still does not link them together.

Top file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TOP is
    Port ( 
        SW      : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        LED     : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0)
        
        );
end TOP;

architecture Behavioral of TOP is

begin


LED(0) <= (NOT(SW(3)) AND SW(2) AND NOT(SW(1)) AND NOT(SW(0))) OR (SW(3) AND NOT(SW(2)) AND NOT(SW(1)) AND NOT(SW(0))) OR (SW(3) AND NOT(SW(2)) AND NOT(SW(1)) AND SW(0)) OR (SW(3) AND SW(2) AND NOT(SW(1)) AND NOT(SW(0)))OR (SW(3) AND SW(2) AND NOT(SW(1)) AND SW(0)) OR (SW(3) AND SW(2) AND SW(1) AND NOT(SW(0)));
end Behavioral;
```

Test bench file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity TestBench1 is
--  Port ( );
end TestBench1;

architecture Behavioral of TestBench1 is

component TOP1 is
    Port ( 
        SW      : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        LED     : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0)
        );
end component;


signal SW      :     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal LED     :     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);


begin


uut: TOP1 PORT MAP(
    SW => SW,
    LED => LED
    );
    

simulation_process :process
begin
    SW(3 downto 0) <= "0000";
    wait for 100ns;
    SW(3 downto 0) <= "1000";
    wait;

end process;


end Behavioral;
```

The error give is this:
[VRFC 10-4940] 'top1' remains a black box since it has no binding entity

Can someone pls help me spot my mistake ?
NB: Sorry if I said something that doesn't make sense. This is the first time I coded an FPGA.

Thanks, I appreciate your guy's help

Comment: There's a default binding indication when a configuration specification is not provided in Testbench1 nor a configuration declaration used as the top of the design. TOP1 isn't found in any reference library made visible by a library declaration (you declared entity TOP, `library work;` is implicitly declared).  Change the references to TOP1 to TOP in architecture Behavioral of Testbench1.

Comment: It's legal to have components unbound in VHDL which is why you can simulate and get no output.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked.